# C++ conversion derived classes

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the code below (c++). I try to explain what I need. I have a base class template and two inherited classes that differ for methods. For each inherited class I need to create the constructor/method that convert the class in the other. The errors are indicated.

```
template < typename T > class A{

protected:
    T **m;

    void allocate_mem(T ***ptr){
        *ptr = new T*[1];
        (*ptr)[0] = new T[1];
    }

public:

    A(){
        throw logic_error("Error!");
    }

    void renew(T val){
        m[0][0] = val;
    } 

    ~A(){
        delete[] m[0];
        delete[] m;
    }

        T say_elem(){
        return m[0][0];
    }

};

template < typename T > class B: public A< T >{

public:

    B(int val){
        A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
        A<T>::m[0][0] = val;
    }

    B(const C &c){    //'C' does not name a type
                      //ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'c' with no type [-fpermissive]
        A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
        A<T>::m[0][0] = A<T>::c.say_elem();
    }

};

template < typename T > class C: public A< T >{

public:

    C(double val){
        A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
        A<T>::m[0][0] = 1;
    }

    C(const B &b){    //'B' does not name a type
                      //ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'b' with no type [-fpermissive]
        A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
        A<T>::m[0][0] = A<T>::b.say_elem();
}
};
```

What I have to do? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please avoid pointers - really!

Comment: I need them, they're necessary!

Comment: Every time you use the * character in C++, a kitten explodes...

Comment: He's got three stars everybody! [Three Stars!](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: Seriously, allocate_mem is horrible. Return a pointer, rather than taking a three-star pointer as a parameter.

Comment: I know that it's stupid to allocate memory for single pointers, i said that i simplified the code (it's a matrix of unknow dimensions). Sorry for my bad english, I will use "derived" and "parent" next times!

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`. See http://ideone.com/3bA689

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the "does not name a type" errors, try forward declaring your classes (ie, put the following lines at the top of your file).

```
template < typename T > class A;
template < typename T > class B;
template < typename T > class C;
```

Then change this: `B(const C &c)` to this: `B(const C<T> &c)`, and the same for the C constructor.

The following code compiles for me:

```
template < typename T > class A {
protected:
    T **m;
    void allocate_mem(T ***ptr){
        *ptr = new T*[1];
        (*ptr)[0] = new T[1];
    }

public:
    A() { throw logic_error("Error!"); }
    void renew(T val) { m[0][0] = val; } 
    ~A() {
        delete[] m[0];
        delete[] m;
    }

    T say_elem() { return m[0][0]; }
};

template < typename T > class C;
template < typename T > class B: public A< T >{
public:

    B(int val) {
        A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
        A<T>::m[0][0] = val;
    }

    B(const C<T> &c) {
        A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
        A<T>::m[0][0] = A<T>::c.say_elem();
    }
};

template < typename T > class C: public A< T >{
public:
    C(double val) {
        A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
        A<T>::m[0][0] = 1;
    } 

    C(const B<T> &b) {
        A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
        A<T>::m[0][0] = A<T>::b.say_elem();
    }
};
```

Comment: expected '{' before ';' token

Comment: Put the second two lines below the implementation for class A.

Comment: I've made a fix, and checked it in my compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The forward declaration answer is almost right, but forward declarations can't specify the parent class. Forward declare like this:

```
template < typename T > class A;
template < typename T > class B;
template < typename T > class C;
```

Comment: is there a way in this forum that allows me to increase your reputation? i'm new...

Comment: You can vote on the usefulness of an answer by clicking one of the arrows to the left of it.

Comment: Ok, but I need reputation 15 to do it (I'm new and only 1)... I'll do it!

Answer (score 0):

You have some circular dependencies between your classes. At a minimum you'll need to provide some forward declarations of your classes. Even then you may need to change the references to pointers because of the method declaration order.